# Question about rails 3 validates_presence_of:

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I saw in rails guides that, mentioning foreign key in model doesn't really create one in db. Is this true with validates_presence_of? Do i need to add the NOT NULL constraint by myself in migration.

P.S When i tried using validates_presence_of in my model, it didn't actually create a NOT NULL constraint. But I'm just a beginner, so i could be missing the obvious. I'm using mysql db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Adding validates_presence_of does NOT automatically add database constraints, if you want them, you need to add them manually.

Comment: I recommend the foreigner gem (https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner), which lets you use add_foreign_key(:from, :to), etc in your migrations.

Comment: @brian yep, i did check out foreigner gem. It was useful.